# R column dataframe names number

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this

```
geo 2001    2002
Spain   21  23
Germany 34  50
Italy   57  89
France  19  13
```

As the names of 2nd an 3rd column are considered as number I'm not able to get a bar chart wth ggplot2. Is there any solution to set the column names to be considered as text?

**data**

```
pivot_dat <- read.table(text="geo 2001    2002
Spain   21  23
Germany 34  50
Italy   57  89
France  19  13",strin=F,h=T)
pivot_dat <- setNames(pivot_dat,c("geo","2001","2002"))
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, that's not exactly true. It is possible to store numbers as names. `names(df) <- c("1", "2", "3")` is valid. I think OP's problem is with the nonstandard evaluation used in `ggplot2`, which uses the form `aes(x = varname)`, where `varname` is the unquoted name of the variable. When the variable name is a number, it will fail to evaluate correctly.

Comment: Would be also good to show what you've tried and couldn't get your desired bar chart.

Comment: You need to post the code you tried and what isn't working. There is a chance you just have an error in your code and don't need to transform the variable.

Comment: This is the code of ggplot2 `ggplot(pivot_dat, aes(x = geo, y = "2008")) + geom_bar()+
  coord_flip()` and I get `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Comment: Can't see any `2008` column in your dataset. That error doesn't have to do with the type of your columns. Use `` instead of "" and use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pivot_dat, aes(x = geo, y = `2002`)) + geom_col()+ coord_flip()
```

by using ticks instead of quotes/double quotes you make sure you pass a name to the function and not a string.

If you use quotes, `ggplot` will convert this character value to a factor and recycle it, so all bars will have the same length of `1`, and a label of value `"2002"`.

**Note 1** :

You might want to learn the difference between `geom_col` and `geom_bar` :

```
?ggplot2::geom_bar
```

In short `geom_col` is `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"`, which is what you want here since you want to show on your plot the raw values from your table.

**Note 2**:

`aes_string` can be used to give string instead of names but here it doesn't work as `"2002"` is evaluated as a number  :

```
ggplot(pivot_dat, aes_string(x = "geo", y = "2002")) + 
  geom_col()+ coord_flip() # incorrect output

ggplot(pivot_dat, aes_string(x = "geo", y = "`2002`")) + 
  geom_col()+ coord_flip() # correct output
```

Comment: I like the `geom_col` alternative to `geom_bar`.

Comment: `ggplot(pivot_dat, aes_string(x = "geo", y = "`2002`")) + 
  geom_col()+ coord_flip()` works for me. I didn't catch the difference between aes and aes_string but the problem was there

Comment: I say that it works in my answer, see my last words `# correct output` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without an example to see exactly what your problem is, and what you want, it is hard to give you a perfect answer. But here's the thing.

You can do a geom_bar with numeric data. There are 3 possible ways I see that you could have problems (but I may not be able to guess every way.

First, let's set up the r for plotting.

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

test <- read_csv("geo,2001,2002
Spain,21,23
Germany,34,50
Italy,57,89
France,19,13")
```

Next, let's make the first mistake...incorrectly calling the column name. In the next example I will tell ggplot to make a bar of the number 2001. Not the column `2001`! r has to guess whether we mean 2001 or whether we mean the object `2001`. By default it always picks the number instead of the column.

```
ggplot(test) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=2001))
```

[image]

Ok, that just gives you a bar at 2001...because you gave it a single number input instead of a column. Let's fix that. Use the right facing quotes `` to identify the column name `2001` instead of the number 2001.

```
ggplot(test) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=`2001`))
```

[image]

This creates a perfectly workable bar chart. But maybe you don't want the spaces? That's the only possible reason you would use text instead of a number. But you want text so I'm going to show you how to use `as.factor` to do something similar (and more powerful).

```
ggplot(test) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(`2001`)))
```

[image]